# OverlayFS - Multiple lower directories and sub directories

Tags: 14.04, overlayfs

I am trying to mount a set of lower directories together imagine like `/mount/ssd_1`, `/mount/ssd_2` etc.. Each of the drives has a set of folders like `ff`, `aa`, `bb`. When I mount the directories like

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mount/ssd_1:/mount/ssd_2 /mount/merged_ssds
```

I go to folder `/mount/merged_ssds/ff` and I only see files from `/mount/ssd_1`. Have I misunderstood how lower directories work? Do I have to use an upper dir instead to have a merged view of all of the subdirectories?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel 4.4.0-28-generic.